# Type Error - Error Handling if data.data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a function that needs to check if the input has already an existing photo in the DB. It can already show if it has already an existing photo. My Problem now is that If I input an ID and it does not have any photo, an error displays. Can you help me in this error?

```
$scope.checkPhoto = function(newSCPID) {
if ($scope.newID == undefined) {
    alert('Please input new id');
} else {
    console.log($scope.newID);
    $scope.loadingloader = true;
    $('#loginloader').show();

    Service.checkPhoto($scope.newID)
        .then(function(data) {
            //$rootScope.loader = true;
            $scope.checkedPhoto = data.data[0].photos;
            //alert(data.data[0].photos);
            if (data.data[0].photos == undefined) {
                alert('Please input newid');
            }

            // alert($scope.checkedPhoto);
            //$rootScope.loader = false;
            $('#loginloader').hide();
            $('#notif').hide();
            // Original Values
        });
    }
}
```

If I input a new ID that has no existing photo, the API displays an error that data.data[0].photos is undefined.

[image]

I need to display a header that there is no existing photo in that particular new ID. How can I do that

Comment: So that means data.data[0] is undefined..... So add a check if it is undefined before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking the photos of undefined, so you need to be checking this `data.data[0]` not this `data.data[0].photos==undefined`, you are getting this because you are trying to check `data.data[0].photos==undefined` when `data.data[0]` is undefined already, and undefined does not have property photos.

Answer (score 0):

Check for data.data[0] before you assign photos;

```
Service.checkPhoto($scope.newID)
                    .then(function(data){
                        //$rootScope.loader = true;
                        if(data.data[0]) {
                            $scope.checkedPhoto=data.data[0].photos;

                           if(data.data[0].photos==undefined)
                           {
                                alert('Please input newid');
                           }
                           $('#loginloader').hide();
                           $('#notif').hide();
                           // Original Values
                        }

                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `data.data` is supposed to be an array. So best to check if the array is not empty before you try to manipulate its items.

```
.then(function(data){
    if (data.data.length && data.data[0].photos) {
        $scope.checkedPhoto = data.data[0].photos;
    } else {
        alert('Please input newid');
    }
    $('#loginloader').hide();
    $('#notif').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a common function that you could use for your whole application like this.

```
function isUndefinedOrNull(val) {
    return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null || val === '';
}
```

And check your value before executing your work. Here is the example below:

```
if(!isUndefinedOrNull(data.data && data.data[0].photos))
{
  alert('Please input newid');
}
```

Comment: A function called `isUndefinedOrNull` should probably not check for an empty string too, or be renamed `isUndefinedOrNullOrEmpty`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, Thanks